# Can I waterdown dry dex to mimic orange peel texture on a drywall repair?

Tags: drywall, repair

Online I see a lot of tutorials that suggest using USG 45 or some other powder mixture to mimic orange peel for a drywall repair. I'm not too keen on buying a big bag when I only need to repair a small patch in my house.

Can I water down some drydex to mimic this?

I've tried the stuff in a can and have been less than impressed.

Comment: Depending on how big the OP texture is, you might get away with a few passes of paint with a thick nap (>1/2") roller.

Answer (score 1):

There are sponges made to use drydex or other compounds and tamp it on the wall. to mimic different textures. ( different sponges for each texture.)
I have used the orange peal sponge. tamped on the compound and let it sit a bit before tamping with a flat sponge to flatten it out.  It was ok, but prefer the spray cans. For unknown reasons, the smaller water based orange peel cans produce a better result than the large "contractor size".  I do use a big piece of cardboard scrap to practice getting the pattern adjusted first.